# Why do I need the field of fractions in the definition of an integrally closed domain?

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra

I have the following definition of an integrally closed domain:

- We say that $R$ is an integrally closed domain if $R$ is an integral domain (i.e. no zero divisors) and if it's integral closure in $\mathrm{Frac}(R)$ is $R$ itself

> Do we only need the field of fractions in the definition of an integrally closed domain since this is the smallest field $R$ can be embedded in?

So I mean we could take any larger field $\mathrm{Frac}(R)\subset K$ in which $R$ can be embedded and then also say that $R$ is an integrally closed domain if $R$ is an integral domain and the integral closure in $K$ is $R$ itself.

Comment: The terminology is best understood by examining the more general concept:  if $\,R\subset S$ is an extension of commutative rings then we define $R$ to be integrally closed in $S$ if every element of $S$ that is integral over $R$ already lies in $R$, i.e. we get no new $R$-integers (roots of monic poly's over $R)$ by extending to $S.\,$  For convenience, in the common special case $R$ is a domain and $S$ is its fraction field we simply say $R$ is integrally closed (i.e. we omit specification of $S$ = "fraction field").

Comment: thanks for the clarity. The statement is very convoluted @BillDubuque

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> We could take any larger field $K$ in which $R$ can be embedded and then also say that $R$ is an integrally closed domain if the integral closure in $K$ is $K$ itself.

In fact that is not correct. For example, $\mathbb{Q}$ is certainly an integrally closed domain. But it is not integrally closed in the field extension $\mathbb{Q}(i)$, since the element $i$ is integral over $\mathbb{Q}$ there. The point is that moving up to a bigger field can add new integral elements over the base ring.

Comment: sorry one small question with $\Bbb{Q}(i)$ you mean $\Bbb{Q}[i]$ or what does $\Bbb{Q}(i)$ mean?

Comment: @Wave yep, that's right! :) the subring of $\mathbb{C}$ generated by $\mathbb{Q}$ and $i$

Comment: thanks and $i$ is integral over $\Bbb{Q}$ because if we consider the polynomial $X^2-1\in \Bbb{Q}[X]$ then $i$ is a root of this polynomial?

Comment: yep, exactly! indeed $i$ is even integral over $\mathbb{Z}$

Comment: Perfect thanks! Your help was very useful!! Hopefully you also see some my other questions in the future;)

Comment: my pleasure, happy it helped! :)

Comment: For all the readers in future, I think I made a typo in the polynomial above it should be $X^2+1$ since $i^2+1=(-1)+1=0$